# If I manage to get an expert spellbook while being novice, can I stil learn it?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

Spellbook ranking system (novice/apprentice/adept/etc) are often described as restriction on what you can buy from merchant, i.e. you won't by an expert book of Destruction magic in a shop if your Destruction level is 5.

But what if I find Transmute spellbook in a cave can I still learn it if I'm a novice in Alteration?

Comment: Technically you can learn it, though you may not be able to cast it since you will usually have low magicka. Unless your higher leveled and just never used that that skill. E.g. You only used Destruction but now want to also use Restoration later on

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, there is no restriction on which spells you can learn. The distinction in spell levels is used, in addition to limiting what sort of spells you can buy from merchants, when applying the perks that halve magicka usage for their corresponding level.

Comment: It doesn't just limit what you buy from merchants.  It also limits what shows up as leveled loot in dungeons.  Therefore, I deduce that OP found the guaranteed copy in (most likely) Halted Stream Camp, and not a leveled copy in some random boss chest, because you *can't find it* as leveled loot until you're high enough level.

Answer (score -1):

Transmute goes great with the mod that adds Electro-mining (mining beam) and Liquifaction (Smelt anywhere).

DanmakuGrazer's answer is correct, but there's a little more to it than that. You *can* learn any spell for which you possess the book.  Your limiting factors in Skyrim aren't tied to your skill so much as your level.  For instance, if you find a Master level book for the spell Infinite Lollerskates (no, it isn't real) when you are level 2, you probably can't cast it due to your Magicka being insufficient.

You certainly won't be able to buy it instead of loot it, either; the leveled lists for merchants are designed to scale the spellbooks with your *potential* spellcasting level. That's why you get a fistful of novice books from the Riverwood trader your first run through, but later on they have a book of Epic Kaboom for sale.

It's also worth noting that the spells in Skyrim do presume the use of enchanted items the higher your casting levels get.  Try casting a Master-level Destruction spell while in your skivvies to see how quickly your Magicka drains.  That worth both ways, though.  If you can get an enchanted helmet/circlet, boots, armor, gloves/bracers/gauntlets, ring, and necklace together which combine to an 85-100% discount on a spell of a given type, you can cast Master level spells out of that school *very* early on.

Just be aware that this is game-breaking if you have mods that unlock disenchanting on the Archmage Robes.  They pack an enchantment called Skein of Magnus which ends up making all of your spells free if you stack it on other armor.

Comment: This is not true.  Transmute is in the base game, and a guaranteed copy may be found in Halted Stream Camp.

Comment: Really.... Goes to show how long it's been since I played vanilla.   I'll edit my answer.... And go hunting. Thanks!